# Column not recognized when using HAVING and AS in SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I am getting an error saying that the total_calories in the HAVING clause is not a valid column:

```
SELECT type, SUM(calories) AS total_calories FROM exercise_logs
GROUP BY type
HAVING total_calories > 150;
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL HAVING SUM GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088727/sql-having-sum-group-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your aggregate column. Alias can only be used in order by or subquery

```
SELECT type, SUM(calories) AS total_calories FROM exercise_logs
GROUP BY type
HAVING SUM(calories) > 150;
```

Comment: . . That actually depends on the database.  Many databases actually do support aliases in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank You for providing information ! I did not know that I was basing this based on SQL server..